# Gradient backgrounds gives default wallpaper on login screen

Tags: login, desktop-background

Today I decided that I was to use a gradient as my Ubuntu Wallpaper, generated by Ubuntu (not an image). It works fine when logged in and when locking the screen, but when I need to actually log into the system it show the default Ubuntu wallpaper.

I run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My previous wallpaper was not the default one. It's an issue for me to use images as gradients simply because I am going change the colors from time to time and this should not happen (my opinion).

I am grateful for any help I may get and I'm glad to give you any information you may request concerning my system, not my motives.

Sincerely.

P.S. I am well aware of that I can have separate wallpapers for login and desktop and I know I can create gradient images. I'm looking for a solution to the issue not an alternative.