# Wallpaper not showing on login screen

Tags: unity, gnome, login, desktop-background

### Problem

I have a custom wallpaper as my desktop background, but it doesn't show up on the login screen and the default Ubuntu Unity "greeter" is shown.

### Past Cases

In the past, they **used to** show up on the login screen too. For example, my very first wallpaper was of Elsa from Frozen, and then something else from an anime Bleach. They showed up when I booted the PC and stayed there as I entered the password.

### Clarifications

I haven't done any major changes to my system. It's Ubuntu 13.10 (don't give me that support has ended thing, it's merely a technical problem that **can** be solved). I also tried putting that picture in the Wallpapers directory (`Home/Pictures/Wallpapers`).

### Why This is Not a Duplicate

[How do I add customized wallpapers so they appear in the dynamic unity greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123381/how-do-i-add-customized-wallpapers-so-they-appear-in-the-dynamic-unity-greeter) is about adding an image to the default directory so that they can be changed via Right Click>Change Desktop.

[How to change login wallpaper?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180625/how-to-change-login-wallpaper) is about having a separate image for background and another for the login screen.

[Gradients backgrounds gives default wallpaper on login screen.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463819/gradient-backgrounds-gives-default-wallpaper-on-login-screen) is about another default wallpaper and it not showing, instead having the default wallpaper.

[Desktop Background doesn't show up on logon screen [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227052/desktop-background-doesnt-show-up-on-logon-screen) is a duplicate that leads to the first question I mentioned here.

And they're all I could find in the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that might fit for you in the following question:
[Changing login screen wallpaper](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313526/changing-login-screen-wallpaper)

They recommend using the following commands:

```
sudo -i
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
su lightdm -s /bin/bash
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter draw-user-backgrounds 'true'
gsettings set com.canonical.unity-greeter background 'imagepath'
exit
```

replace imagepath with your actual image path and then it should work fine. Make sure that your path is correct, because otherwise it may result in a black background.

Comment: Will you make it a standalone answer please? It worked, and that question is not defining this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me this is was a file permissions problem. I fixed this by setting image permissions in nautilus to:

```
Owner - Read and Write 
Group - Read and Write 
Others - Read only
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could make this work in 16.04 was to have my custom wallpaper image masquerade as a default system wallpaper, as follows:

1. As su, copy the image to /usr/share/backgrounds
2. As su, edit /usr/share/gnome-background-properties/$(lsb_release -cs)-wallpapers.xml
3. Copy and modify one of the "<wallpaper>" elements to register the new wallpaper.
4. Save the file.